# Google Webmaster Tools 'index status' and 'sitemaps' are not consistent

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

In Google Webmaster Tools, **Google Index** -> **Index Status** shows 40 indexed pages:

[image]

However **Crawl** > **Sitemaps** shows 5 indexed pages, and 35 submitted:

[image]

There are no crawl errors in the sitemap.

Why are these numbers inconsistent? How many pages is Google actually indexing?

Comment: This answer will explain a lot about these metrics and why they do not jive: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have indexed pages that are not included in your sitemap.

**Google Index -> Index Status** - shows all pages that are indexed for your domain.

**Crawl > Sitemaps** - shows which pages were indexed from the sitemap you submitted

This is normal. However, if the number grows quite large for a small site you might have to plug a few holes using your robots.txt file. Here is some sample code:

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: */personal-folder/
```

Also, keep in mind that GWT is not very accurate and information doesn't get updated at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I understand that not all submitted pages are indexed (and how robots.txt works) but I still don't see why it's saying 40 pages are indexed rather than 5 elsewhere in the UI. Also those 40 pages are all unique - ie, blog articles with large amounts of unique content, so I'm not sure why they're  not being indexed.

Comment: Because Index Status shows total # of pages indexed and Sitemap shows how many pages from your sitemap were indexed.