# Possible to check which links in a sitemap are indexed and which ones aren't?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, sitemap, google-index

Is it possible to check which links of the sitemap I've submitted are being indexed, and which ones are not?

I've submitted my sitemap.xml without errors. When I check the sitemap in google search console, it says 174 links are sent, but only 120 are indexed.

So I'm looking for an option/tool that lets me check which links are indexed and which ones are not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nope, there's no way. However, the closest you'll get is selecting a long period of time in Analytics and then exporting all the pages that received organic search traffic.

Comment: @TimothyVGoyvaerts I am on the fence whether this can be done reliably. There are two answers here and I am not sure which is correct. However, this answer may help to understand things a bit better and perhaps you can tell us.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 Please do tell us what does work!!

Comment: This was flagged as "very low quality", presumably because it is very short and because the answer is a simple "not possible".     This answer would be better with a reference or by explaining some very tedious ways to check every URL by hand, but I believe that this is the correct answer in this case, so I'm leaving it up.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i suspect, it was flagged because of factual incorrectness

Comment: factually incorrect answers should not be flagged.  Comment on the incorrectness and possibly downvote.

Comment: well, tnx guys for downvoting. Now please explain to me how is this done. And i mean, in the way that I need 10minutes to finish that work. Not whole day. Please. Enlighten me.

Comment: so? how it's done? @Evgeniy

Comment: @JosipIvic i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can. make a Google query `info:www.your-site.com/your-page.html` - if the page URL is indexed, it will appear in index and you will see it, if not - not.

To get things done quick:

- create a csv file with all sitemap urls, which are manipulated to the `info`: Google query. URLs should be like this:

  - https://www.google.de/search?q=info:www.example.com/page-one
  - https://www.google.de/search?q=info:www.example.com/page-two
- with following iMacro run queries on by one and check the SERP page - if it contains your page, it is indexed and iMacro saves its title to the file. If  page isn't indexed, iMacro writes #EANF# into file.

iMacro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE sitemap.csv 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=indexed.csv
```

Comment: That sounds very labor intensive to do for every URL in a sitemap.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller nothing complicated at all: create a list of query urls like `https://www.google.com/search?q=info:http://www.example.com/page1.html` and then let an iMacro run through the list and collect the output of the SERP page. Thing of 15 minutes.

Comment: Using automated tools to perform searches is against the Google terms of service and will likely get your IP address put on the "captcha required" list.

Comment: making random time gaps between queries proven helps against this. i make at least 35 seconds between queries, or use VPN. if somebody doesn't want to violate against Google's ToS by his own, can pay money for a service, which breaks ToS and delivers data.