# Number of results on Google's 'site:' search

Tags: seo, seo-audit

I have come across something puzzling with Google's 'site:' search results. When searching a site that I know to have far more than 10 million indexed pages, Google displays 564,000 results. Is there any reason/logic behind this? Is this an indicator of a large number of indexed but low quality pages?

[image: site search results]

Comment: This answer may clear a few things up!! http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Comment: That's awesome, cheers!

Comment: @BLL27 We get questions about the `site:` operator quite a lot [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=site+operator+is%3Aquestion).  If there's something different about your question from the one marked as a duplicate, or the answers aren't sufficient there, just edit the question to make that distinction and it will be added back to the review queue for reopening.