# Redirected site to www and submitted www URLs but Search Console only shows 5 pages indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Recently I submitted the www version of my site to Google Search Console and 301 redirected all URLs from non-www to www. I submitted the URLs in my sitemap.xml.

The problem is that I've submitted 62 URLs and only 5 are indexed! The non-www version shows 89 indexed and the sitemap shows 5 indexed. The www version also shows 5 indexed.

I checked through Google search using ‘site:www.example.com’ and it shows 8 pages. For non-www it is 89.

Is there a problem?

Comment: It will take sometime until all your pages are indexed. Have you uploaded the sitemap.xml directly to webmaster tools, or only added to your site?

Comment: first i have added in site than submit to webmaster tools

Comment: If your non-www site search shows 89 but your sitemap indexed shows 5, then I would check the urls on your sitemap match what you are expecting to be indexed. Because this might not be something that time sorts out, it could be that the sitemap is wrong. Not that it will affect the move from nonwww to www, but it will mean the reporting wont be accurate, now or in the future.

Comment: This answer may help you to understand these metrics better. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score 2):

> Recently…

You need to wait. It takes a while for Google to update their index and even longer to update Google Search Console. Be patient and it should all settle correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for the changes to appear in Search Console. The links will move from one version to another.

However, i would like to think that you have already set your preferred version. It should be the one you are redirecting to