# Can't index my WordPress site on Google (Bing,Yahoo Ok)

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am trying to make my WordPress site appear on Google but without any luck. I have already signed and verified with Webmasters Tool , submit a sitemap there, checked the *robot.txt* and *.htaccess* files, checked for no-index,no-follow and also unchecked the discourage search engines in WordPress reading settings. Everything seems ok , but its over 1 month now without any luck. There are some crawl stats but the site:`www.example.co.uk` gives 0 results and the `site:example.co.uk` gives only the cPanel subdomain (?).

Bing and Yahoo indexed the page from the beginning. I am using GoDaddy for hosting and WordPress 4.4.2. Is there any other way I can check if this is an error from the WordPress installation or the Hosting side?

Comment: This answer should clear up some of the confusion between the metrics: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 It may help your understanding. Do a Fetch as Google and Render to see if Google can see your pages okay. You can also use Submit to Index. But only do this for a couple of example pages. It still takes G a couple of days to actually include the fetched pages in the index so do not panic. It may take more than a month for a site to be indexed. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Check in the webmaster tools Crawl -> Fetch as Google. Fetch and render some page from your website. It will give you results of what Google sees and what is blocked.

Search for you meta title in Google, exact match. Maybe it is an issue of duplicate content with your older websites.

Check if your canonical link (if you have such) is pointing to correct URLs.

Hope that will help.
Good luck