# Google just un-indexed 8000 of our URLs, what could be possible reasons?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

We went to our sitemaps and discovered a fall in the number of indexed pages, while the submitted pages remained more or less the same.

Some sitemaps look like this now:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the following sitemap the submitted pages went up, while the indexed pages has gone down:

[image]

And in some sitemaps the pages seem unaffected:

[image]

It could be a website problem where our pages are not accessible to Google.
Could someone confirm that this isn't google playing around? Or that we aren't being penalised.
This has never happened to us.

Also our search traffic has been actually going up for the past few months, so this is surprising.

Update:

This Question was posted on the 13th of May 2016.

This article came out on the 13th of May 2016:
https://www.seroundtable.com/index-counts-in-google-sitemaps-reporting-drop-22078.html

Seems like there might be a Google Bug.

Comment: Is the canonical URLs different to the sitemap URLs? We have a situation like that in Shopify where our product URLs have a different canonical URL than those in the auto-submitted sitemap - so we only have 9/2000 'indexed' which is by design.

Comment: @inkovic No that does not seem to be the case. :/

Comment: Cause every single one of your page is pure spam. At least that's my guess based on the information provided.

Comment: Likely this : https://www.seroundtable.com/index-counts-in-google-sitemaps-reporting-drop-22078.html

Comment: If Google can crawl your pages, it will use the sitemap for auditing it's ability to fetch pages. It is not uncommon for the sitemap index count to go up and down by wide margins almost endlessly. This answer explains the metrics and what can be trusted for what: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 If your pages are indexed as seen in Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools), Google Index > Index Status then you are okay.

Comment: As it is, users can only offer guesses as to possible causes. If you can edit this to add more details that they can base their answers on, then it will be added back to the review queue for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my website once. I have submitted about 80K URLs and Google indexed about 72K URLS. Later it slowly removed most of the pages. What I found is that the pages which I have submitted has thin content. And also, Poor architecture might be secondary reason.

So check if all pages having unique and sufficient content and resubmit.