# Indexing status from webmasters vs site:domainname.com method?

Tags: google-search, sitemap

I went to google and typed in the search box site:example.com and I found out that there are 96 pages results on my website name. Below is the screenshot of it
[image]

And I have submitted sitemaps using Google webmaster tools (28 webpages and 68 images). The status of indexing shown is pending. I had submitted 2 days before.
If the status on webmaster is pending then how come google shows 94 results on my website name?? Does that mean my website is been crawled as well as indexed?
Is this a good thing?

Comment: Sorry but its not clear what your asking, please edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer help clear things up for you? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Comment: I too have no idea what you are asking. If you can clarify, that would help. Cheers!!

Comment: A `site:` search can return results that don't necessarily get returned in a "normal" Google search. This can explain the "pending" status. However, the fact that these results are returned at all means your pages have certainly been crawled and are at least in the process of being indexed. Yes, it's a good thing. Indexing takes time; patience.

Answer (score 1):

As Google indexed your site the indexed pages and keywords are added into the index in near real time and go live into production. The reason why the index status is pending is because the crawl and evaluation of keywords has not yet been fully completed. For a new site this can take up to two weeks at times though frequently it is faster than that.