# Google Search Console only showing one page in index status, while many pages indexed in sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am using Google webmaster tools for my site. I recently have changed address. Now, I wonder why the number of indexed pages in Crawl -> Sitemaps and Google Index -> Index Status are different?

Comment: Did you add the new domain name as a property in Search Console? I assume the index count will decrease for the old site and increase for the new site.

Comment: Yes already. And yeah i'm talking about the new domain here. It shows 80 indexed pages in Sitemaps but it shows 1 in Index Status, is there a reason that they are different regardless of the change of address.

Comment: It just plain takes a while to build up the metrics. These are two separate sites. As the old one unwinds, the new one will upwind. Here is an answer about the different metrics that may help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Comment: The site has been deployed for over a year already but the change of address was only 3months ago, so is it okay that there's only 1 indexed page?

Comment: No. That seems suspicious to me. Did you 301 redirect the old domain to the new??

Comment: Yes the previous domain, the non-www, and the http all 301 redirects to the new https://www.domain, so it's really weird. And in google webmaster tools I can't select a preferred domain, it says due to the Change of Address.

Comment: I have avoided the Google Change of Address so I do not know how it behaves. Sorry. It sounds like something is confused.

Comment: Do you have an HTTPS version of the site?   Do you have both www and no-www versions?   If you have both, did you register all four of the resulting variants to Google Search Console?

Comment: Yes I have all of them. And I have registered them all as Google suggested.

Comment: This may be a bug in Google.   Somebody else just asked the exact same question: [Why my Google Index Status is only 1?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98351/why-my-google-index-status-is-only-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep calm.  There are many different caches, datacenters, and latencies in the Google indexing system. If your new domain is set up properly and the whole site (including the sitemap) is available for the bot, you'll eventually see the correct numbers. It can take up to three months.

Comment: You're right. It just took sometime. I was worried I may have broke something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that the [Google Index Status report has been broken](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-index-status-report-fix-22600.html) for the last weeks or months.  It hasn't been getting any new data.

[Google just announced](https://plus.google.com/events/ca26c8hah45bvc7eof8foupf6lk) (Friday, Aug 26, 2016) that they fixed it.  Your report will start showing more indexed pages if it hasn't already done so.