# What is the difference between the searches site:http://example.com and info:http://example.com?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

What is the difference between the Google site indexing search tools of `site:http://example.com` and `info:http://example.com` ?

The reason I ask is that `site` search shows hundreds of pages for my site; the `info` search only returns the home page.

In GWT, Google Index>Index Status shows no URLs, yet the sitemap section Crawl>Sitemap shows hundreds of indexed pages in the sitemap; this must be the root of the difference.

What must have caused this: I had deleted my site and sitemap and resubmitted after I changed my entire site from `http` to `https`. I have a 301 redirect for all URLs from `http` to `https`.

I also used Crawl>Fetch and Render to resubmit my home page and all linked pages about a month ago after I resubmitted the sitemap.

Do I just wait for indexing and for the info search to catch up with the site search?

Comment: If you have not added a property for HTTPS in Google Search Console, do so. HTTP and HTTPS are two different sites. If you change from HTTP to HTTPS, then the pages indexed in HTTP will drop to 0 while HTTPS will rise from 0.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `site` search shows hundreds of pages for the site and the `info` search only returns the home page is in because the `site` operator get results from your domain, it list all the webpages that Google has indexed. The `info` operator just get information about a web address, its cached version, similar pages, and the ones that link to the site.

Example:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com shows all the site pages that Google has indexed.
- https://www.google.com/search?q=info%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com just
  list basic info about it and links to get further information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But why the different in GWT? I.e. "In GWT, Google Index>Index Status shows no URLs, yet the sitemap section Crawl>Sitemap shows hundreds of indexed pages in the sitemap."

Comment: That is completely separate issue: [Google Search Console only showing one page in index status, while many pages indexed in sitemap](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98306/google-search-console-only-showing-one-page-in-index-status-while-many-pages-in)