# Why has the number of indexed pages reduced for my site on Google?

Tags: seo, google

I published my website a few days ago, and I tried to check the indexed status of my site in Google, so I searched Google for the following words: ‘site:example.com’.

At first, there is only 1 result. Then after a while, I noticed that some Google bots tried to fetch my site. I got 200+ results after I searched again but there are 15k+ pages inside my website.

And when I run the search again and again, I found that the results reduce! Now there are only 80+ pages.

Are there possible reason which can cause this kind of suitation?

Comment: This can be a SERP filter, but most often, it is just a refresh of the SERPs which happens a few times a day. ;-) This answer will help you not to freak out: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to setup Google Search Console and submit the sitemap which will highlight any major errors that could be stopping the indexing of pages on your site.