# Why the number of indexed URLs in Search Console dropped?

Tags: google-search-console, url, search-engine-indexing, google-index

A few months ago I saw there were 14 URLs reported as indexed in Google Search Console.  As of a few days back, it's showing that only 3 URLs have been indexed.

Do I have to request that it index 14 URLs again, or it will it eventually update on its own?

Comment: How old is your site?   If you do a `site:` search on Google for your site, how many URLs do you see there?

Comment: This answer may help to understand the metrics you see and what is real and what should be ignored. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The first step to take would be to search for your site in Google by doing a site:example.com search. This will show you how many URLs are being picked up by Google. Also, in Search Console, check to see if it is saying that 14 have been submitted and only 3 have been indexed? This may be due to issues on the site. Check in the 'Issues' column if this is the case as that can shed some light on the issues.

Comment: thank you very much 14 urls have been submitted...... thank you.....