# Drop in XML Sitemap Index Numbers in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

what is going on .. my sitemaps aren't index anymore...
I have a real[image]ly sudden decreasing in sitemap index

Comment: We get this question ALOT!! I feel your pain. This answer should explain things a bit: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I can understand it feels really hopeless when this kind of things has been there in your Search Console.

This is happening because you've lots of pages in your website.

To make sure all of your important pages would get indexed you've to set crawl budget and crawl rate of your website.

There must be some pages that are not needed to be indexed, remove them and do as above stated.

I hope it is going to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "set crawl budget and crawl rate of the website"

Comment: But it shouldnt be for pages ... because we dont change our submitted total index and it just increase and raise and just two days later it starts to decrease