# Google Search Console reports the number of indexed pages in the sitemap fluctuates

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, google-index, xml-sitemap

We have a large site. The number of indexed pages in our sitemap has been decreasing and increasing constantly in the last month.

What should I do? Is there a special reason?

Comment: I think google was updating its google webmaster console infrastructure that's why it's happening. I've submitted my website sitemap and see some issue like indexing decreasing than past.

Comment: But this update is for mobile data

Comment: Read this. It may help. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808