# Does the below-mentioned server header impact google indexing?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, cache-control

```
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 06:26:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.11.33.5-0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Content-Length: 9418
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: **My indexing is too slow on webmaster(google)** Does the settings mentioned above has any effect on the google crawling rate and indexing ?

Comment: What's "too slow"?

Comment: Google url indexing ( Sitemaps submitted includes 157000 urls) . Google has only indexed 800 urls. Its been almost a 20 days now since i first submitted my sitemap.The submitted sitemap have no errors listed in search console.

Comment: This answer will help to make things clear: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you do on your end can really affect the crawl rate Google uses. You have the ability to slow down crawls through webmaster tools but there is no way to speed it up through webmaster tools or through your site. Your headers look fine and appear to be much the same as many sites out there. If Google has slowed down after having a long time of frequent re-indexing it may be due to not detecting much updated content and so not needing to recrawl regularly. If it is a relatively new site then Google won't have gotten up to speed with it as it can take some time before Google starts doing regular crawls. The only thing you can really do is regularly update your site and be patient.

During the crawling process there are two headers which mainly come into play and they are the `Last-Modified` header and the `If-Since-Modified` header. What happens is that the first time a page is requested by the crawler it saves the `Last-Modified` header if it is available, and the next time the page is crawled it will send the `If-Since-Modified` header. Now if the server (or proxy if there is one in the process) is configured to handle this request it will check to see if the requested page has been updated since the last time it was crawled. If it has then it will return the full page but if it hasn't then the server will return a 304 not modified header without a document (saves time and bandwidth).

Now I should note this is the way it works if the server has been configured to handle it otherwise the request will always result in a document being returned to the crawler but the headers you have specified do not really play a part in SEO (extremely low, possibly non existent signal). They can play a part with crawl frequency if the caching was configured or the expire date was in the future but as your's effectively says never cache and always get the latest copy from the server as it always expires then it won't be having an effect on crawl rates.

Comment: Doesn't the **Expires** and **Cache-Control** affect SEO and slows crawling and user response ?

Comment: Only if they are set in the future, if they are set in the past it is the HTTP-ese way of saying "Hey you don't cache this, come ask me every time for the latest copy as I will probably have something new to say every single time". See my updates answer for more info as well as how caching can be optimised for crawling purposes.

Comment: Regardless of what this header is set as (caching or not) it shouldn't affect the initial (first time) indexing of that page, which appears to be the problem here.

Comment: @ChrisRutherfurd While you can't increase the speed of the crawls, you can increase the duration by increasing your site authority and site speed. Lower the authority, the less Googlebot resources allocated, fact.

Comment: @SimonHayter - Aware of this and completely agree, I was trying to limit my response to the question of the headers as the OP provided in order to not complicate the matter, but yes increasing site authority will increase the duration.