# No results in google SERP

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing

My website is showing 245 pages indexed in Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools), but in Google SERP it is showing no results? My website is 2 months old, in GSC there are no crawl errors, but a `site:example.com` search is giving no results.

Can anyone tell me why not?

Comment: This answer should help understand the difference between the GSC Index Status and the results of a site: directive. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score -1):

It can take a while before google starts adding your site to its index.

Comment: Although 2 months is a reasonable length of time and submitting pages through GSC is often "instant". Also, how do you explain the apparent inconsistency between GSC and a Google `site:` search?

Comment: I'm voting this answer down because it is so short.   A one line answer is never sufficient to answer a question here.   Good answers list several factors.   Good answers are backed up with references or personal experience.