# Difference between "site:" search and "Index Status"

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I'm getting confused about `site:example.com` and "Index Status" part in Google Webmaster Tools.

`site:example.com` list four pages but "Index Status" has a 0 as "Total Indexed".

I don't know what's the difference between these two.

Comment: Seeing if this answer helps... https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Answer (score 1):

Google Search Console doesn't show accurate data most of the time and it takes some time to update the data while "site:" will show you exact and real time website index data.

So I would suggest you to wait for Google Search Console data to be updated. Don't depend solely on the data of the Search Console.

Also have a look at this answer for in depth explanation: [Number of indexed pages with "site:" search less than reported in Google Webmaster Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808)

Comment: you mean both `site:example.com` and `Index Status` do the same job?

Comment: Yes, both does the same job but the Index Status shows historical data & how many URLs are blocked from search, etc while the site:example.com shows the real time index status of the indexed pages of the website.