# Google reports almost nothing from the sitemap is indexed even though millions of pages are indexed overall

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, xml-sitemap

In google webmaster tools, I am seeing a very big discrepancy between `Crawl >>> Sitemap >>> indexed`
[image: Crawl >>> Sitemap >>> indexed]

and
`Google Index >>> Index Status`
[image: Index >>> Index Status]

although when i search on google for `site:mysite.com`, it gives me another number which is 320000! any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: `site:` is not to be used as a indication of how many pages are indexed as its majorly wrong in high numbers. Google Search Console is not real time and can be several months behind, especially on index count on sites with high volume of pages.

Comment: This answer will help to clarify these metrics. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 It will make sense of the metrics.

Comment: It sounds like you are not submitting your canonical URLs in your sitemap.   Can you make sure that you are submitting preferred URLs that don't redirect?