# Google search console shows that a version of my domain that isn't preferred and isn't indexed still gets some search traffic. Why?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

My client's website has several properties in search console that are variations such as `https://www...` and `http://www...`.

I would expect the preferred version (`https://www`) to get all the search traffic.  However other versions such as `http://www` shows a small amount of traffic, even though its index status is 0.

Why could that happen?

Comment: Does the http version work on some of the pages? Or is the domain fully redirected to https?

Answer (score 1):

If it is fairly new, the index status take some time to update. I suggest you to check if it is indexed on Google by searching for `site:example.com`. This will reveal the real indexed pages.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, thank you for the comment. Already considered all that; the site is not new, and I also checked through site:yoursite.com, but it obviously only shows https pages, so still does not make sense.

Comment: Using the site: directive does not show the number of indexed pages. It shows the number of indexed pages that pass all of the SERP filters that apply. Only the Search Console can show the number of pages indexed, however, it can be a month or so behind. My answer here explains the metrics. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808