# Google Search Console reports more pages from the sitemap are indexed than the overall count. A site: search gives yet a third number

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

When i checked in Google Search Console in Google Index -> Index Status that time only **36 URL** Indexed. [image]

But When i check in Crawl Section --> Sitemaps  that time 616 webpages submitted and 249 webpages indexd.[image]

Again, i check in Google.com (Google Search Results with site:xya.com) that time i can see that 299 webpages are show on Google Search Results Page.

Comment: The `site:` search is known to be inaccurate.  Google has said they provide poor estimates for counts in that type of search.   See [Number of indexed pages with “site:” search less than reported in Google Webmaster Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast)  I'm not sure why the two numbers reported within Search Console are so different.

Comment: Your site looks brand new, at least your search console graph shows zero until just recently.   Google doesn't index all the pages on pretty much *any* site.   Expect the number of indexed pages to grow over time as you get reputation and inbound links.   Eventually Google will probably index 90% or more of your pages, but it could take months or years to get to that point.

Comment: This is old search console. Check new version, in sitemaps report click on index button for each sitemap and see how many indexed, excluded, or errors. Also there are index coverage report, showing not only indexed pages but also excluded, error, indexed with warnings. Since your site is in indexing process, check again later. _This two reports possibly generated on different time._

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the site is new so expect some fluctuations, give some time to get everything indexed and shown.

I would also recommend using the new search console as is more accurate on whats indexed and what is submitted, the best thing is to compare what you have above with what the new console is shown but overall just give it few more days (about a week)

Few things to consider:

1. Google is using mobile first index so make sure your site is
   properly optimized for mobile.
2. Crawl and index and 2 different things Google first crawls and then
   indexes the pages.