# What does "submitted and indexed" mean in the coverage report from Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I added my website in Google Search Console and submitted a sitemap there.

[image]

What does it mean by "submitted and indexed?" I think it says the pages are available in Google, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried search for `site:www.wixten.com` and pages that is says are submitted and indexed don't show up.

What does "submitted and indexed" actually mean?

Comment: It shows up in the search results for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnn2B.png

Comment: Related: [Number of indexed pages with "site:" search less than reported in Google Webmaster Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast)

Answer (score 1):

The site: search is not exhaustive. URLs that are indexed may not be included.

Indexed means it can be shown in search results. Try making a real query that relates well to the page's content.

Submitted means it is in your XML sitemap that you told GSC about. I think it also includes URLs manually submitted for indexing.