# How to get precise indexed page number from a certain domain or a certain site?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index

When conducting competitor analysis, we use "site" command to get the indexed page number from a certain domain or a certain site.
But it seems that I cannot get the correct(or precise) number.

For example,

"site:sample.com", I get about 10000 results.
"site:a.sample.com" I get about 20000 results.

"a.sample.com" is a subset of "sample.com", i.e., the indexed page number of "site:a.sample.com" should be less than the indexed page number of "site:sample.com".

Do I misuse the "site" command?
Are there any other better solutions to get correct(or precise) indexed page number from a certain domain or a certain site?

---

Some people said that google search does not display all the indexed page results. 
Refer to this article:
[Why the number of indexed pages decreased for a “site:” search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18287/why-the-number-of-indexed-pages-decreased-for-a-site-search)

Are there any official articles about this subject?

Comment: sample.com and a.sample.com are two separate sites and not one is a sub-set of another. See this answer for an idea of what the metrics mean: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for sharing this information. It is a good answer for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about `site:www.sample.com vs site:a.sample.com` OR `site:sample.com vs site:a.sample.com`

Google usually shows all subdomains when you do `site:sample.com` including results from `a.sample.com` but if you do `site:www.sample.com` (where www is a subdomain), it shows only results from www.sample.com.

Even in case of `site:sample.com vs site:a.sample.com`, the results count may vary a lot because site: is not a reliable source of getting true number of indexed pages. I personally have seen large differences in indexed pages when comparing site: to webmasters count.

> Are there any other better solutions to get correct(or precise)
>   indexed page number from a certain domain or a certain site?

Google webmasters is precise but that's for websites you own. Also, how comparing 'count of indexed pages' of competitors is helpful to you? It's just a number indicating indexed pages with no bearing on ranking. Probably, the only helpful inference you can draw from it is how deeply google is indexing your competitor's website and I believe site: may be good enough indicator of that.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and let me re-examine it.

I am curious about the following numbers of search results.

"site:*.ruten.com.tw", I get about 667,000 results.
"site:class.ruten.com.tw", I get about 4,310,000 results.

Comment: And...I use the "site" command to get the amount of the indexed page number from a certain domain or a certain site because I want to figure out how RSS and keyword directory affact google search indexing.
For example, Newegg use RSS and Taobao use keyword directory.
In my opinion, RSS is for search engines that index pages effectively, and keyword directory is benifit from link building and let pages rank better.

That's why I ask this question.

Comment: For "site:*.ruten.com.tw", I get about 22 million results. For "site:class.ruten.com.tw", I get about 4.3 million results. Not sure, why you are getting so few results for "site:*.ruten.com.tw".

Comment: I get about 22 million results, too. But I get about 669,000 by private surfing.